# Delete App - Delete Status History?

Tags: facebook, publish, wordpress

I was instructed to delete my App and recreate it in order to resolve an issue with compatibility with the 2013 breaking updates.

The App is used to create status updates for a page based on posts to a Wordpress Blog.

When I deleted the App, all of the status updates seem to have been deleted along with it?

Can anyone explain why and what I need to do to restore the updates?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you have to delete the app to update the code? But no, when an app is removed so is the content it uploaded as far as i know

Comment: By deleting the app, you've lost its namespace... But that's another topic.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an app all content it produced in Facebook is also removed (or at least no longer is visible to anyone).  You can try contacting Facebook and ask them to undelete your application, but most likely they won't (or can't).  So, unfortunately you've lost all of those updates and have to start fresh with a new app.

Comment: How do you go about contacting Facebook?  I can't find a link anywhere to request anything like this.

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure they'll just tell you that they can't undelete the app.   Who told you to delete it in the first place?  If it was someone from Facebook then you should talk to them.  Otherwise, you can try some of these links:  http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Contacting_Facebook